# Where do the configuration settings live in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, config, settings

I am learning python and want to edit the configuration files of VSCode to toggle the selected theme, but I can't find the file controlling the configuration settings. The below file-path is where I've narrowed it down to so far:

`C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`

I've also come across this thread from 2016
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10046
Which pointed me here, though I'm still sifting through the thread
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3884#issuecomment-230912738

This thread is from 2016, and the old and new versions they mention are not up to date.

`Old Settings: %APPDATA%\Code[ - Variant]\User\settings.json`

`New Settings: %APPDATA%\Microsoft\[Visual Studio ]Code[ - Variant]\settings.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current user setting locations are covered [in the VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations):

- Windows: `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
- macOS: `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
- Linux: `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

(For insiders, use `Code - Insiders` instead)