# where is vscode configuration under Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code

edit: I will try this later, but it turns out that extensions are allowed to put their configuration anywhere on the filesystem, and sometimes do.  [Completely uninstall VS Code extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746857/completely-uninstall-vs-code-extensions)

VS Code is great, but when it breaks, it really does. I would like to start over after my Jupyter configuration stopped working. I am aware of  [Where do the configuration settings live in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60556147/where-do-the-configuration-settings-live-in-vscode) , and removed $HOME/.config/Code . That seems to have had an effect but my previously installed extensions are still showing as installed. How do I start with a *clean* vscode under Linux, no extensions, no anything, please?

The reason I am asking is that I used to be able to select "Python: Run Current File in Python Interactive Window", and it just worked. Now it fails to start without providing any sort of a reasonable starting point for fixing it. I see several questions asking about this with answers that helped others but not me (a fair few are "it mysteriously recovered"), so asking another probably will not help.

Comment: nuke `~/.vscode/extensions`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Completely uninstall VS Code extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746857/completely-uninstall-vs-code-extensions)